# Not seeing always allow in android location permission

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-permissions

I have been trying to use an react native ble librairie ([react-native-ble-manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager)). In order to use this the user have to allow location permission (as explain in the documentation android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION if android API >= 29.
I request the autorisation as their example with:
(PermissionsAndroid is from the react-native librairie) :

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >= 23) {
            PermissionsAndroid.check(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION).then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    console.log("Permission is OK");
                } else {
                    PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION).then((result) => {
                        if (result) {
                            console.log("User accept");
                        } else {
                            console.log("User refuse");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

On my device the pop-up ask me for the autorisation with only two choices :

- Only when the application is running
- Refuse

But with their example I have 3 choices the two others and "always authorise"

And for some reason I'm not able to scan peripheral if I don't always approve (I have been able to change to always for my application by going in the settings of it).

Part of my android manifest (android/app/src/main) (as you can see I have background_location)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
```

I'm sure I'm missing an obvious thing but I can't see what..
In advance thank you :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For those having the same issue : my phone has android 11 so it can't be directly requested in the pop-up.
You have to indicate to your user how to change the permission
Source : https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include the most important information in the link provided in the answer itself. This can help prevent your answer from becoming invalid if the link stops working or the content significantly changes.